# Using Text Fixtures -- Google Test

Tags: c++, tdd, fixtures, googletest

I have a class and I am planning to test it using Google Test Framework.
I am curious why is there need for "Text Fixtures"? (as described here: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer). Can't
I just use several TEST() macros? why are fixtures necessary?

Answer (score 2):

They are not strictly necessary, but will allow you to share variable initalizations and scaffolding code that is shared by many different but related tests. In short, it's a convenience feature that allows you to write much shorter tests. This helps readability as well as to shorten your test-code cycle in TDD.